# Microsoft Word Regular Expression for Email Address

Tags: regex, ms-word, expression

I need to create a regular expression for an email address that will work with **Microsoft Word's** find and replace. I am not trying to get any complicated regex, just a simple one will do.

I found many regexs on the web, but Word doesn't allow the use of carrets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [piece of VBA macro](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/validate-email-vba.html) that you can check:

```
Option Explicit

Const MODULE_NAME As String = "modMail"
Public Function ValidateEmailAddress(ByVal strEmailAddress As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Catch

    Dim objRegExp As New RegExp
    Dim blnIsValidEmail As Boolean

    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.Pattern = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$"

    blnIsValidEmail = objRegExp.Test(strEmailAddress)
    ValidateEmailAddress = blnIsValidEmail

    Exit Function

Catch:
    ValidateEmailAddress = False
    MsgBox "Module: " & MODULE_NAME & " - ValidateEmailAddress function" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
        & "Error#:  " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[A-z,0-9]{1,}\@[A-z,0-9,\.]{1,}
```

You can use this